# Why is su preserving SHELL=/bin/bash in this case?

Tags: bash, su

I was experimenting with switching users with the `su` command. I'm confused why su carrying the `SHELL` environment variable over to a user `monty`. The exercise is shown below:

```
vagrant@cats:/home$ cat /etc/passwd | grep -E "monty|vagrant"
vagrant:x:900:900:vagrant,,,:/home/vagrant:/bin/bash
monty:x:1000:1002::/home/monty:
vagrant@cats:/home$ cat /etc/default/useradd | grep SHELL
# The SHELL variable specifies the default login shell on your
SHELL=/bin/sh
vagrant@cats:/home$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
vagrant@cats:/home$ ssh monty@localhost
monty@localhost's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-31-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
Last login: Wed Sep 28 17:34:36 2016 from ::1
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh
$ exit
Connection to localhost closed.
vagrant@cats:/home$ su monty
Password:
monty@cats:/home$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
monty@cats:/home$ exit
exit
```

As can be seen above:

- There are at least two users `vagrant` and `monty`
- `vagrant` has a specified shell of `/bin/bash`
- `monty` has an unspecified shell which should default to `/bin/sh` as shown in `/etc/default/useradd` file

  - this is backed up by sshing into monty and checking the shell
- except then weirdly why using `su monty` the `SHELL` env variable stays as `/bin/bash`

That last bullet is the main reason why I'm confused. Taking a look at `man su` doesn't seem to help either, notice the `-s` flag:

```
-s, --shell SHELL
           The shell that will be invoked.

           The invoked shell is chosen from (highest priority first):

               The shell specified with --shell.

               If --preserve-environment is used, the shell specified by the $SHELL environment variable.

               The shell indicated in the /etc/passwd entry for the target user.

               /bin/sh if a shell could not be found by any above method.
```

Going down the list:

- I didn't use the `-s` or `--shell` flag, so that doesn't explain anything
- I also didn't use the `--preserve-environment` switch which would explain the situation, but doesn't because I didn't use it
- There is no shell in the `/etc/passwd` for the target user, which should mean it defaults to `/bin/sh`, so that doesn't help
- It would be make sense for a lack of an entry and all the above fags or switches to cause nothing to be found, except then `/bin/sh` would be used...which it isn't, so that doesn't help either

So I'm really confused, it seems like I'm literally seeing a perfect inversion of any behavior one could expect after reading through every config file and man entry on this issue haha.

Would love some help and guidance :)

Edit: See answer and comment below. Also see the first and second to last paragraph in the DESCRIPTION section in the man page

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ...The optional argument - may be used to provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.
>
> ...
>
> The current environment is passed to the new shell...

Comment: see this question/answer: http://superuser.com/questions/453988/whats-the-difference-between-su-with-and-without-hyphen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`su` by default preserves the current user's environment when switching to another user, this includes the current user's shell.

To use the target user's environment and configuration, you need to start a **login shell** by adding the `-l`/`--login` option or simply a `-`:

```
su - monty
```